# How can I unit test an MVC Action that returns a PartialViewResult?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, action

I have an `Action` as follows:

```
public PartialViewResult MyActionIWantToTest(string someParameter) 
{
    // ... A bunch of logic
    return PartialView("ViewName", viewModel);
}
```

When I inspect the result, It has a few properties, but they are either null, or empty.
The only property that has anything is the `ViewEngineCollection` which doesn't contain anything specific to my method.

Does anyone have some example code that tests a `PartialViewResult`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say you have an `Action` that looks something like this:

```
public PartialViewResult MyActionIWantToTest(string someParameter)
{
   var viewModel = new MyPartialViewModel { SomeValue = someParameter };
   return PartialView("MyPartialView", viewModel);
}
```

Note: `MyPartialViewModel` is a simple class with only one property - `SomeValue`.

An NUnit example may look like this:

```
[Test]
public void MyActionIWantToTestReturnsPartialViewResult()
{
    // Arrange
    const string myTestValue = "Some value";
    var ctrl = new StringController();

    // Act
    var result = ctrl.MyActionIWantToTest(myTestValue);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("MyPartialView", result.ViewName);
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<MyPartialViewModel>(result.ViewData.Model);
    Assert.AreEqual(myTestValue, ((MyPartialViewModel)result.ViewData.Model).SomeValue);
}
```

Comment: Also MvcContrib.Testhelper has a AssertPartialViewRendered() extension method.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me. I did the following to resolve the test failure I was seeing.

This was my action:

```
    [Route("All")]
    public ActionResult All()
    {
        return PartialView("_StatusFilter",MyAPI.Status.GetAllStatuses());
    }
```

I had to give the result a type in order for it to work. I used PartialViewResult for my action returning a Partial View, as opposed to my other actions that return a full view and use View Result. This is my test method:

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void All_ShouldReturnPartialViewCalledStatusFilter()
 {
     // Arrange
     var controller = new StatusController();
     // Act
     var result = controller.StatusFilter() as PartialViewResult;
     // Assert
     Assert.AreEqual("_StatusFilter", result.ViewName, "All action on Status Filter  controller did not return a partial view called _StatusFilter.");
  }
```